# MySQL Full Join Three Tables

Tags: php, mysql

There is a Q/A discussion system with three tables for three level Q/A comments. Table 3 (level three comment: `GPcommentsFollowup2`) is related to table 2 (level two comment: `GPcommentsFollowup`) and table 2 is related to table 1 (level one comment: `GPcomments`). Level 2 and 3 are actually followup comments of Level 1. I want to extract the contributions of each user showing the tree at which level the user contributed. For example:

```
L1-- Title:
|--L2-- Title:
    |--L3-- Title:
    |--L3-- Title:
|--L2-- Title:
    (no L3 contributed)
|--L2-- Title:
    |--L3-- Title:
    |--L3-- Title:
    |--L3-- Title:
L1-- Title:
    (no L2 and L3 contributed)
```

I tried the code below, but the return value is empty. Is there any suggestion.

```
function userGroupContributions($pdo, $topicGroupId, $userId1){
$query= 'SELECT L1.commentTitle AS L1T, L1.commentId AS L1Id, L2.commentTitle AS L2T, L2.commentFollowupId AS L2Id, L3.commentTitle AS L3T, L3.commentFollowup2Id AS L3Id FROM GPcomments AS L1
        FULL OUTER JOIN GPcommentsFollowup AS L2 ON L1.commentId = L2.commentId
        FULL OUTER JOIN GPcommentsFollowup2 AS L3 ON L2.commentFollowupId = L3.commentFollowupId
        WHERE (L1.userId=? OR L2.userId=? OR L3.userId=?) AND topicSessionId=?';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($userId1, $userId1, $userId1, $topicGroupId));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $L1Id = $row['L1Id'];
    $L2Id = $row['L2Id'];
    $L3Id = $row['L3Id'];
    $L1T = htmlspecialchars_decode($row['L1T']);
    $L2T = htmlspecialchars_decode($row['L2T']);
    $L2T = htmlspecialchars_decode($row['L2T']);

    $data .= '<div>'.$L1T.'</div>';
}
return $data;
```

}

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: I tried LEFT JOIN and UNION and RIGHT JOIN but did not work again.

Comment: just use JOIN and also provide any errors that are outputting. check logs and the such.

Comment: left joins from top to lower levels should work, as I get it. using simple join you loose comments without follow ups at lower levels.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it with this code:

```
$query= 'SELECT L1.commentTitle AS L1T, L1.commentId AS L1Id, L1.commentsTypeId AS L1Type, L2.commentTitle AS L2T, L2.commentFollowupId AS L2Id, L2.commentsTypeId AS L2Type, L3.commentTitle AS L3T, L3.commentFollowup2Id AS L3Id, L3.commentsTypeId AS L3Type FROM (SELECT * FROM GPcomments ORDER BY submitDate DESC) AS L1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM GPcommentsFollowup ORDER BY submitDate DESC) AS L2 ON L1.commentId = L2.commentId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM GPcommentsFollowup2 ORDER BY submitDate DESC) AS L3 ON L2.commentFollowupId = L3.commentFollowupId
        WHERE (L1.userId=? AND L1.topicSessionId=?) OR (L2.userId=? AND L2.topicSessionId=?) OR (L3.userId=? AND L3.topicSessionId=?)
        UNION
        SELECT L1.commentTitle AS L1T, L1.commentId AS L1Id, L1.commentsTypeId AS L1Type, L2.commentTitle AS L2T, L2.commentFollowupId AS L2Id, L2.commentsTypeId AS L2Type, L3.commentTitle AS L3T, L3.commentFollowup2Id AS L3Id, L3.commentsTypeId AS L3Type FROM (SELECT * FROM GPcomments ORDER BY submitDate DESC) AS L1
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM GPcommentsFollowup ORDER BY submitDate DESC) AS L2 ON L1.commentId = L2.commentId
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM GPcommentsFollowup2 ORDER BY submitDate DESC) AS L3 ON L2.commentFollowupId = L3.commentFollowupId
        WHERE (L1.userId=? AND L1.topicSessionId=?) OR (L2.userId=? AND L2.topicSessionId=?) OR (L3.userId=? AND L3.topicSessionId=?)';
```

Comment: Try not to ask questions in answers. Stick to answering this question, and if you have a different question (the one about ordering), look around for an existing answer and if there is none you can ask a separate question.

Comment: Statement: Level 3 can't exsist without Level 2 and Level 2 can't exsist without Level 1. If this statement is correct you can just replace FULL with LEFT.